# Can't change the view depending on the size of the list

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have problem with change view on my layout on my RecycleView.I have list dream. This view contains two state myDreamEmptyLayout witch show Text "For now you don\'t have dream. \n Add dream!" when myDreamList is empty and size is equals 0. But when myDreamList size more than 1 show list dream.
Problem is when have myDream on list and delete all can't show my view myDreamEmptyLayout.
What is problem ?

This is my fragment_my_dream.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="match_parent"
             android:background="@color/colorBackground"
    >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/myDreamEmptyLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/for_now_you_don_t_have_dream_n_add_dream"
            android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"/>

    </LinearLayout>


    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/myDreamRecyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:visibility="gone"/>
</FrameLayout>
```

This is my fragment class

```
   public class MyDreamFragment extends Fragment {

        public static final int REQUEST_CODE_CREATE = 1;


        @BindView(R.id.myDreamRecyclerView)
        RecyclerView myDreamRecyclerView;
        @BindView(R.id.myDreamEmptyLayout)
        LinearLayout myDreamEmptyLayout;

        private MyDreamAdapter myDreamAdapter;
        private List<MyDream> myDreamList;
        String idUserString;
        private DbHelper dbHelper;
        private Unbinder unbinder;
        private Dao<MyDream, Integer> myDreamDao;
        private Dao<User, Integer> myUserDao;

        @Override

        public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setHasOptionsMenu(true);
        }

        @Nullable
        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_my_dream, container, false);
            unbinder = ButterKnife.bind(this, rootView);
            TextView title = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.toolbarTextView);
            title.setText(R.string.title_my_dreams);
            return rootView;
        }

        @Override
        public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

            Application application = (Application) getApplicationContext();
            idUserString = application.getFirebaseId();

            dbHelper = new DbHelper(getActivity());

            try {
                myDreamDao = dbHelper.getDao(MyDream.class);
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            try {
                myUserDao = dbHelper.getDao(User.class);
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            QueryBuilder<User, Integer> userQa = myUserDao.queryBuilder();

            try {
                userQa.where().eq(User.Columns.FIREBASE_ID, idUserString);
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            QueryBuilder<MyDream, Integer> myDreamQa = myDreamDao.queryBuilder();


            try {
                myDreamList = myDreamQa.join(userQa).query();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            if (myDreamList != null && myDreamList.size() > 0) {
                myDreamRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
                myDreamAdapter = new MyDreamAdapter(myDreamList, getActivity());
                myDreamRecyclerView.setAdapter(myDreamAdapter);
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
            super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
            inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_add, menu);
        }

        @Override
        public void onResume() {
            super.onResume();

            if (myDreamList.size() == 0) {

                myDreamEmptyLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                myDreamRecyclerView.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            } else {

                myDreamEmptyLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                myDreamRecyclerView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            }
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

            switch (item.getItemId()) {
                case R.id.action_addream:
                    Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), AddEditDreamActivity.class);
                    startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE_CREATE);
                    return true;
            }

            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }


        @Override
        public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

            if (resultCode == AddEditDreamActivity.RESULT_OK) {
                if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_CREATE) {
                    if (data != null) {
                        MyDream myDream = data.getParcelableExtra("dream");
                        myDreamAdapter.addMyDream(myDream);
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Dream was added", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onDestroyView() {
            super.onDestroyView();
            unbinder.unbind();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `myDreamList` will not react to pending changes and as such `myDreamEmptyLayout` will not get informed of that new information (such as size reached zero) is available. To counter this look at [this ObservableArrayList](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/databinding/ObservableArrayList.html) and its [OnListChangedCallback](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/databinding/ObservableList.OnListChangedCallback.html). After changing the `myDreamList` to `ObservableArrayList` move `onResume` code (without `super` of course) to `OnListChangedCallback` and add this callback via `addOnListChangedCallback`. This way the changes done to the list will be reflected on the layout as you desire.

The code:

```
//this goes to onCreate. DISCLAIMER : code written without testing, please confirm that it works.
myDreamList.addOnListChangedCallback(new ObservableList.OnListChangedCallback() {

/*snipped useless methods*/

     @Override 
     public void onChanged(ObservableList<T> sender) {
            if (sender.size() == 0) {

                myDreamEmptyLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                myDreamRecyclerView.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            } else {

                myDreamEmptyLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                myDreamRecyclerView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            }
        }
}
```